# Which technology can connect with Cassandra as well as NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, apache-spark, architecture, cassandra

I am using `spark streaming` for reading `TCP server` and then inserting the data into `Cassandra`, which I have to further push to UI, for pushing I decided to go for `NodeJS`. But I am not getting any technology which can talk with Cassandra as well as NodeJS. Below is my architecture, and I am not able to find out technology which can replace `?` I am also open to change Cassandra with `MongoDB` if it is possible to directly push data from Mongo to NodeJS. But as of now I am using Cassandra as it have native support for `Hadoop`.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the datastax nodejs-cassandra driver: https://github.com/datastax/nodejs-driver project. This has cassandra row streaming and piping functionality that you could use to push cassandra data into node, process, and then export via websockets per your desired architecture.

leave your stream client open - and this would need to run as a persistent node server handling errors - something like this should pick up new cassandra data:

```
var streamCassandra = function(){
  client.stream('SELECT time, val FROM temperature WHERE station_id=', ['abc'])
  .on('readable', function () {
   //readable is emitted as soon a row is received and parsed
   var row;
   while (row = this.read()) {
    console.log('time %s and value %s', row.time, row.val);
  }})
 .on('error', function (err) {
  //handle err
  })
 .on('end', streamCassandra);
};
```

wrap your stream client into a recursive function that calls itself again on('end', streamCassandra). you could also poll the function every x seconds with a setInterval if you dont need that kind of concurrency. One of those approaches should work

Comment: thanks @steveinatorx for your reply, I have checked that datastax #stream API, but it will not continuously fetch data from Cassandra, instead it will bring all data and display once. If you have implemented the same in other way please post it here. Thanks.

Comment: will `#stream` return the latest inserted records or it will bring old records as well as we are firing same query?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked NiFi?

https://nifi.apache.org/

In your case, you could write your Spark Streaming results to Kafka, HDFS, or even directly to NiFi, but I personally prefer to write to Kafka or some other message queue.
From NiFi, you can write to Kafka, and also send requests to your Node JS app if that's what you need. In my case, I'm using Meteor, so just pushing from Kafka to MongoDB automatically refreshes the UI.

I hope it helps.

Comment: One of the solution we have if using Kafka, and from Kafka NodeJS will keep on reading and then using socket communication it will push to UI.

Comment: thanks @alghimo for the reply, please elaborate your last point "How just pushing from Kafka to MongoDB will automatically refreshes UI, are you using Meteor to write data to MongoDB?"

Comment: Meteor bundles a MongoDB instance, so when you start your app, there is also a MongoDB that starts. Then, if you insert data into MongoDB, Meteor will "see" it and refresh the UI.